# String subscript out of range error for code that traverses string c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, subscript

I am trying to count the count the number of positive numbers, negative numbers and zeros in a string of space separated integers. The number of integers in the input string is specified by the user.

The code compiles fine, however every time I try to run it, it crashes with the error "Debug Assertion Failed. ... Expression: String subscript out of range".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int n, x;
    int positives = 0;
    int negatives = 0;
    int zeros = 0;
    std::string ip;
    char space = ' ';
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin >> ip;
    while (i < n) {
        if (ip[i] != space) {
            x = (ip[i]);
            if (x > 0) {
                positives++;
            }
            else if (x < 0) {
                negatives++;
            }
            else if (x == 0) {
                zeros++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the length of n? what’s the value of p? Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Is `n` in `while (i < n)` a string?

Comment: Why would you read the data into a string if it is integers and you want to perform comparisons on them? First, `>>` with strings stops at the first space, so you won't read it all. Second, the individual characters of a string aren't going to be the integers you want to compare. They might be part of one if it s more than one digit, and they will be characters like '0', or 48 in ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start `std::cin >> some_string_var` is going to *stop* at the first white space character it finds, so there's little point in using that to search for spaces separating words.

You would be better off just reading in *integers* and just comparing them directly with zero. Here's how you could do with with the MNC (minimum necessary change) on your code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int n;
    int positives = 0;
    int negatives = 0;
    int zeros = 0;
    int value;
    std::cin >> n;
    while (i < n) {
        std::cin >> value;

        if (value > 0)
            positives++;
        else if (value < 0)
            negatives++;
        else
            zeros++;

        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "p=" << positives << ", n=" << negatives << ", z=" << zeros << '\n';
}
```

A sample run follows, keeping in mind the initial `4` is a count rather than one of the values:

```
pax:~> ./prog
4
0 1 2 -99
p=2, n=1, z=1
```

---

If you were looking for something a little robust, you could use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int quant, pos = 0, neg = 0, zer = 0, value;
    std::cout << "How many input values? ";
    if (! (std::cin >> quant )) {
        std::cout << "\n*** Invalid input.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (quant < 0) {
        std::cout << "\n*** Negative quantity input.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (int count = 1; count <= quant; ++count) {
        std::cout << "Enter value #" << count << ": ";
        if (! (std::cin >> value )) {
            std::cout << "\n*** Invalid input.\n";
            return 1;
        }

        if (value > 0.0)
            pos++;
        else if (value < 0.0)
            neg++;
        else
            zer++;
    }

    std::cout << "Positive value count: " << pos << '\n';
    std::cout << "Negative value count: " << neg << '\n';
    std::cout << "Zero value count:     " << zer << '\n';
}
```

It's a little more user friendly on communicating with the user (both in terms of what is requested, and the results generated). It's also a little more robust in detecting bad input.